# implement dynamic row colour based on 1 column data in dynamic datatable using p;columns

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, datatable, dynamic-tables

I am creating a dynamic datatable using p:Columns.
i want to apply color to the row based on one column value dynamically,
currently able to implement on one column,

kindly help me with set the color on row dynamically by using column data.
here is the code.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{sampleMB.rows}" var="row" resizableColumns="true" scrollable="true">
                <p:columns value="#{sampleMB.mapperList}" var="column" style="text-align: center; min-width:50px; background-color:#{ 
                    row[column] eq 'EXTERNAL' ? 'red' : row[column] eq 'INTERNAL' ? 'green' : ''}" sortBy="#{row[column]}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{column}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{row[column]}" />
                </p:columns>
                        </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Try rowStyleClass tag of <p:dataTable>, And give you logic https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/rowColor.xhtml

Comment: I cant add the logic to the rowStyleClass, as per the above code we are getting the columns data after iterating inside p:columns...the same data how can we use for rowstyle before even iteration. Please provide some sample code if you have.

Comment: Can you put more code in question, like your #{sampleMB.rows} type of rows and #{sampleMB.mapperList} type of mapperList, their should be some way.

Comment: I have used  List<Map<String, Object>> rows to set from DB (Select* from table) , here map key is getting set with table header and map value object is setting with corresponding data.
List<String>mapperList  is column headers to match with map key,
p:datatable is iterating the data from the map and p:columns in iterating with the column headers and passing the header to the map to getting the corresponding value to show in h:outputtext.
now I want to color the row by using column value

Answer (score 0):

Define color desired color combination in "td" in STYLE section of JSF

```
<style type="text/css">
    .colored td{
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
```

Use it in dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable value="dataModelList" var="current"
    .....
    rowStyleClass = "#{BooleanTest ? '' : 'colored'}" 
>
```

Comment: And how do you do the booleanTest based on the value of something in the `p:columns`?

Comment: Here an example:
rowStyleClass = "#{current.valid ? '' : 'colored'}"

Comment: That is **not** from the columns tag but from the datatable. Read the second comment. _"I cant add the logic to the rowStyleClass, as per the above code we are getting the columns data after iterating inside p:columns...the same data how can we use for rowstyle before even iteration."_. Otherwise this question was just a duplicate of other questions